# rewrite order on firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I wan´t to make routing with firebase hosting

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "/**",
    "function": "myfunction"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

/api/test should route to api function

/anything should route to myfunction

/ should route to index.html on firebase hosting

for some reason/api/test is being routed to myfunction. I can´t get the rewrite order right. can you help me? thanks

update: this is what I have now

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "build",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "cleanUrls": true,
        "trailingSlash": false,
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "/api/**",
                "function": "api"
            },
            {
                "source": "/**",
                "function": "myfunction"
            }
        ]
    },
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
    }
}
```

and myFunction is the one that´s still being executed and ignoring what I set

/api/test is executing myfunction instead of api
/something/test is executing myFunction as expected

Comment: This looks good according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order). Maybe there is something in app logic or configuration is not updated somehow?

Answer (score 0):

"/" (or no slash at all after your domain name) automatically routes to "index.html". So simply remove the `"source": "**"` item. Specifically remove:

```
,
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
```

I also like to add the following to my Firebase Hosting config (`firebase.json`):

```
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false,
```

Comment: thaanks for the cleanUrls and trailingSlash advice. my problem was actually on the first rule the one with /api/** is not being routed to the function

Comment: I will appreciate if you can take a look at my question above. thank you so much.